# How Can I limit bit number in the integer variable in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, cryptography

I want to realize [IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm) algorithm in Python. In Python we have no limits for variable size, but I need limit bit number in the integer number, for example, to do cyclic left shift. What do you advise?

Comment: Implement your own wrapper class that imposes these restrictions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the [BitVector](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitVector/2.0.1) library.

Example of use:

```
>>> from BitVector import BitVector
>>> bv = BitVector(intVal = 0x13A5, size = 32)
>>> print bv
00000000000000000001001110100101
>>> bv << 6                            #does a cyclic left shift
>>> print bv
00000000000001001110100101000000
>>> bv[0] = 1
>>> print bv
10000000000001001110100101000000
>>> bv << 3                            #cyclic shift again, should be more apparent
>>> print bv
00000000001001110100101000000100
```

Comment: So the `<<` operator modifies in-place? I thought it must be a typo and you meant to write `<<=` but your code is correct. Dubious design choice there.

Answer (score 2):

An 8-bit mask with a cyclic left shift:

```
shifted = number << 1
overflowed = (number & 0x100) >> 8
shifted &= 0xFF
result = overflowed | shifted
```

You should be able to make a class that does this for you. With a bit more of the same, it can shift an arbitrary amount out of an arbitrary sized value.

Answer (score 2):

The [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module might be of help (documentation [here](http://packages.python.org/bitstring/)). This example creates a 22 bit bitstring and rotates the bits 3 to the right:

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> a = BitArray(22)   # creates 22-bit zeroed bitstring
>>> a.uint = 12345     # set the bits with an unsigned integer 
>>> a.bin              # view the binary representation
'0b0000000011000000111001'
>>> a.ror(3)           # rotate to the right
>>> a.bin
'0b0010000000011000000111'
>>> a.uint             # and back to the integer representation
525831
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a the low 32 bits of a number, you can use binary-and like so:

```
 >>> low32 = (1 << 32) - 1
 >>> n = 0x12345678
 >>> m = ((n << 20) | (n >> 12)) & low32
 >>> "0x%x" % m
 '0x67812345'
```